# sql workbench/j won't display any objects in Database Explorer

Tags: sql-workbench-j

I'm using Sql Workbench/j to connect to a sybase (actually sql anywhere) db using Sybase jConnect.  I am able to query the database without issue.  However, if I launch the Database Explorer to view what tables are available, but nothing is coming up.

Any thoughts?  I must have a bad configuration somewhere, but I don't know where.

Comment: Have you selected the required schema / catalog?

Comment: I don't see where to select that - I can pick the Owner and database, but not the schema/catalog.

Comment: n/m - I see that owner is the schema and database is the catalog, so yes, I am selecting that.

Comment: if I select dbo, I see the system tables, but that is about all I'm able to see.

Comment: got it - if I just pick * for the schema, I'm able to see everything - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have selected the required schema. After the schema is selected you will see all objects of that schema. If the loged-in user has rights on all schemas then you can also choose * in Schema drop-down list.See attachment.

[image]